# how to get the actual file occupied size(file with hole) through java api?

Tags: java

working with java get file size, one of case is:
i create one file on linux with hole, as the following:

```
ls -ltr hole.f 
-rw------- 1 root root 1073741838 Apr 15 09:56 hole.f
```

the size returned by ls , is 1073741838, but the actual occupied size is just 8k.

```
du -sh hole.f 
8.0K    hole.f
```

File.length return as 1073741838. is there any java api could return 8k?

i do not want to use RunTime api.

ps: jnr could not resolve my requirement as there is run time exception:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: stat.st_blocks is not implemented in jnr-posix
        at jnr.posix.util.DefaultPOSIXHandler.unimplementedError(DefaultPOSIXHandler.java:28)
        at jnr.posix.JavaFileStat.blocks(JavaFileStat.java:105)
        at AA.main(AA.java:30)

Comment: What do you mean with "i do not want to use RunTime api." ? What is "RunTime api" ?

Comment: Runtime.exec()  and such...